# How to decrypt rich text data exported in dxl using lotus script?

Tags: encryption, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

i am using lotus script code to export items in dxl file. here is the code.

```
Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim filename As String
Dim stream As NotesStream
Dim exporter As NotesDXLExporter
Set db = session.Currentdatabase
set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
filename = "c:/temp/exportDocs.dxl"
set stream = session.createStream()
If stream.Open(filename) Then
    Call stream.Truncate()
    set exporter = session.CreateDxlExporter()
    exporter.Richtextoption = 1
    exporter.MIMEOption = 0 
    Call stream.WriteText(exporter.Export(dc))
End if
```

End Sub

after data is exported.i am getting body of item in this type

gv9aAAEAAAAAAAAA..........encrypted data.

i have decode this buffer into base64 and i am getting my data. but i am getting some header in my data after base64 decoding . the starting signature of header buffer after base64 decoding is 0x5AFF82. can anyone tell me how can i decrypt it.?

Comment: Why don't you use `exporter.Richtextoption = 0`? It wouldn't convert RichText data into base64.

Comment: @Knut: i need to get body by parsing dxl. if i use exporter.Richtextoption = 0 then i it will be vry difficult for me to parse the richtext data as it contains lot of format tags. i just need text from body not its format and all..

Comment: `exporter.Richtextoption = 1` should contain all format tags too. I'd write an agent in Notes which copies the text part of RichText into a new Text item and read that instead. The formula agent could look like this: `FIELD BodyText := @Abstract([TEXTONLY]; 64000; ""; "Body")`

Answer (score 1):

Because the field is rich text, "the data" are not just text, but include formatting, maybe pictures, tables, hyperlinks and so on. It sounds like you want to extract just the text.

Why do you feel you need to do this with DXL? The NotesRichTextItem class has a Text property that will pull out just the text, which is what you seem to be saying you need. Even if the DXL is needed for some other reason, you could get the text out this way and replace or augment the rich text contents in the DXL with a CDATA containing just the text.

If for some reason the DXL is an essential part of the process for you: 
The rich text is made of "CD Records" which each include a header followed by some data. All the text is inside of "text run" CD records, but there are many other types. The header information of the CD records is standardized such that you don't need to be able to recognize one to skip over all the ones that don't contain text. So it's not too difficult to write code to scan that base64 data and extract out just the ones that contain your text. However, the text is LMBCS-encoded, so you'll need to do some fiddling to decode it if it's not all in the ASCII range. The C API Guide describes the CD format.